# Android Listview Inside viewpager always showing last viewpager page arraylist data in all pages

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager

**Its a viewpager that contains the listview having answers for particular question.**

Listview(**Arraylist**) have all the data page by page, I have checked it on logcat via PrintLn. So the problem is only the that, in all the viewpager pages listview is showing last page answers(data) in all pages of viewpager.

I also tried **holder.adapter.notifydatasetchanged();** but its not working.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my screen, showing the Question and below is the list of answers]

Here is my code as below,

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View convertView = null;

        convertView=inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();

    holder.lvCaseAnswers = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvCaseAnswers);
    holder.lvCaseAnswers.setTag(position);
    holder.txtCaseChallengePostedBy=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaseChallengePostedBy);
    holder.txtCaseChallengeQuestion = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaseChallengeQuestion);
    holder.txtCaseChallengeCategory = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaseChallengeCategory);
    holder.btnCaseChallengeSubmit=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCaseChallengeSubmit);
    //btnCaseChallengeTry=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCaseChallengeTry);

//get data from list
    System.out.println("que_id: "+listItems.get(position).getQue_id());
    dbconn.open();
    c=dbconn.getQuestionById(listItems.get(position).getQue_id());
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        //set data from database
        Toast.makeText(context, "data:"+c.getString(0), 0).show();
        holder.txtCaseChallengePostedBy.setText(" Posted By "+c.getString(2));
        holder.txtCaseChallengeQuestion.setText(c.getString(4));
        String category = c.getString(3);
        category = category.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + category.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        holder.txtCaseChallengeCategory.setText(category);

        holder.listanswers.add(c.getString(5));
        holder.listanswers.add(c.getString(6));
        holder.listanswers.add(c.getString(7));
        holder.listanswers.add(c.getString(8));
        holder.listanswers.add(c.getString(9));
        System.out.println("list item name:"+holder.listanswers.get(0));
        holder.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.raw_answers, holder.listanswers){

            @Override
            public View getView(int position,
                    View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Integer txtPosition = (Integer) parent.getTag();
                LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_answers, null);
                TextView txt=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtRawAnswers);

                CheckedTextView text = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRawAnswers);
                text.setText(holder.listanswers.get(position));
                if(holder.listOptions.get(position).equals(holder.correct_ans))
                {
                    text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.custom_radio_btn, 0, R.drawable.ic_true, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.custom_radio_btn, 0, R.drawable.ic_false, 0);
                }
                return view;
            }
        };
        holder.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        holder.lvCaseAnswers.setAdapter(holder.adapter);
        holder.lvCaseAnswers.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        Constants.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(holder.lvCaseAnswers);

        holder.correct_ans=c.getString(10);
        holder.answer=c.getString(11);
        holder.txtCaseChallengeUserAnswer.setText(holder.answer);

        for(int i=0;i<holder.listOptions.size();i++)
        {
            if(holder.listOptions.get(i).equals(holder.answer))
            {
                holder.lvCaseAnswers.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.lvCaseAnswers.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }

        holder.lvCaseAnswers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                holder.answer=holder.listOptions.get(position);
            }
        });
        holder.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        holder.lvCaseAnswers.setEnabled(false);
        holder.btnCaseChallengeSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    }
    dbconn.close();
    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(convertView);

    return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting different position of viewpager ?

Comment: yes... thats why questions are showing proper in each page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't used **Fragment** in viewpager. Use viewpager with fragment. It will work.